# How do I cipher plaintext using ECDH?

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, ecdh

I'm looking for sample Java code to implement the cipher for ECDH encryption. I've already found the method to get the keys required but still haven't found a solution to encrypt the text. Appreciate if anyone can give some guidance.

Btw I am using SpongyCastle as I am programming for Android.

Many Thanks!

Comment: ECDH is normally used for key agreement, not for actually encrypting something. You would want to use a symmetric cipher (such as AES) for that for a variety of reasons, speed being one.

Comment: I tried using AES but I keep getting this error java.security.InvalidKeyException Key Length not 128/192/256.

Comment: 8The gory detail is in [NIST SP 800-56A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56A/SP800-56A_Revision1_Mar08-2007.pdf). Look at sections 5.8.1 and 6.1.2 in particular.

Answer (score 3):

ECDH is not an encryption algorithm; it *cannot* encrypt some data you choose. It is a [key agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol) protocol, which results in a "shared secret": the data which both sender and receiver end up sharing is "secret" (only them know it) but they cannot control its contents.

The idea is that you can use the shared secret as the basis for a symmetric encryption algorithm. Since the shared secret has a relatively non-flexible format (with ECDH, the shared secret is an elliptic curve point, and about half of it is really secret), the normal way is to hash it with a secure hash function (say, SHA-256) and use the hash output (or part of it) as the actual encryption key.